# Алгоритм проверки четности

Tags: java

Данная программа проверяет является ли число простым, а нужно прописать алгоритм по проверки является ли число четным

класс:

```
package prime;
public class Prime { 
     public boolean definePrime(int n) { 
           prime = n;
            for(int i=2; i<prime/2; ++i) { 
                 if(prime%i == 0) 
                     return false;
            }
            return true;
     }
      private int prime; 
}
```

тестер

```
package test; 
import prime.Prime; 
import org.junit.runner.*; 
import org.junit.runners.*; 
import org.junit.Test; 
import static org.junit.Assert.*; 
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.Collection; 
@RunWith(Parameterized.class) 
public class PrimeTester { 
     public PrimeTester (int n, boolean expected) { 
          prime = new Prime();
          this.n = n;
          this.expected = expected; 
     }
     @Parameterized.Parameters 
      public static Collection getNumbers() { 
          return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
              {1, true},
              {3, true},
              {6, false},
              {7, true} 
          });} 
       @Test     
       public void test() { 
            assertEquals(expected, prime.definePrime(n)); 
      }
       private int n;     
       private boolean expected;     
       private Prime prime; 
}
```

Comment: четное число при делении на 2 дает в остатке 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean isEven(int i) {
    return (i % 2) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isEven(int i) {
    return (i & 1) == 0;
}
```

Тогда уж так, хотя может компилятор сам заменяет эту операцию

Comment: как это не странно, но компилятор не произвел замену и варианты с & и % компилируются в разные байткод инструкции: iand и irem соответственно. При том, что на моем синтетическом тесте ваш вариант оказался немного быстрее

Comment: Хороший код :) - люблю битовые хитрости

Comment: `((i >> 1) << 1) == i`